# Outlook meeting for 2nd working day of month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

Is there a way to set a recurring monthly meeting for the 2nd working day of each month.
(assume Sat & Sun are non working days)

So if the month starts on a Saturday the meeting would be Tuesday 4th.

If the month started on a Wednesday the meeting would be Thursday 2nd.

From the available recurring options, working day does not seem to be an option, so I'm not that hopeful, but maybe with VBA ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your screenshot, the option below selected is: The first tuesday of every 1 month.

If you set this enabled, those options can be changed. First can be changed to Second and Tuesday can be changed to weekday by scrolling up, and it will do exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: I have been meaning to post this question for ages, and the option was right under my nose the whole time, I added an image to your answer also, hope you don't mind

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Was about to add one myself, but my language is dutch, so this is much better. :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your sharing.