# How to have a recurring meeting on the 14th working day of the month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

The answer supplied here is not valid [Outlook meeting for 2nd working day of month](https://superuser.com/questions/1591124/outlook-meeting-for-2nd-working-day-of-month)

The drop down suggested only allows you to select the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th working day of the month. Beyond that it is useless.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Copy the appointment and paste into the appropriate days. Natively the only way. Otherwise build a Macro to see if you can do it that way.

Comment: Due to the design, there are no other options except these options, to workaround it, it is recommended you manually copy the appointment and paste it to the date you want to set.